# Managing App Users/Groups in a iPhone App

Tags: iphone, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, sqlmembershipprovider

I'm looking at managing user groups in an iPhone App. The App is connected to a WebServer.
I'm therefore looking at using ASP.net Membership Provider to store/manage User Info. 
(We may just make a simple custom table to manager end users).

I have not seen a native User Management framework in iphone SDK.
Anyone have a better suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution for this? I'm after something very similar for an iPhone app. that integrates with the aspnet_Membership.